# Email server with multiple subdomains

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email-server, subdomain, hostname

Here is my scenario. 
I have main website named example.com just showing about the company history and other static info along with subscription package. When a client buys the package then we do the integration of bought product on his server. All the code and database is deployed on client's new server but the his application is run as a subdomain on our main server like this: `client1.example.com`.
Same thing happens on client 2 and so on. 
On my main server I have an email server setup at `example.com`, now when the client's users send email from their subdomain account like `client1.example.com` then I want the sender address to be of main domain like `sender@example.com` rather than `sender@client.example.com`. 
It is our requirement that sender email ID should have hostname of main domain rather than subdomain.

I have postfix installed on client system, all clients are handled using ubuntu instances. Emails are being sent normally from clients app but with the sender address of subdomain like `sender@client.example.com` which is not what our company wants. But if we make the sender address from main domain from subdomains of clients like `sender@client.example.com` then since both machines have different IPs and sender IP will be different from the domain IP.

- What should I do in this case?
- Add some DNS entry for each subdomain?
- Also one thing, do I need SPF and DKIM for each subdomain?

Thanks for your insight and help.

Comment: duplicate but yes ptr dkim and spf is required

Comment: you could also use their email system with salsauth relay

Comment: Ummm, no. You should probably read the Postfix documentation on address rewriting, though (http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html). This is a pretty common scenario in the mail delivery environment, and you will need to configure your client*.example.com systems to forward mail to the example.com server and masquerade their hostname.